# How do I check in c++, if a vector of strings contains char 'p'

Tags: c++, algorithm, iterator, copy, std

1 ) Let's say I have a vector `v` of Wizards (Wizard has a name, lastname, vector of strings which includes subjects that he/she attends, and a house where he/she belongs)

2) I have an empty vector `cpy`, where I want to copy those wizards, who attend a subject, that has a letter 'p' in it.

In my case, I would like to copy only Laura, because she attends sports, which is the only subject containing 'p'.

```
//wizard.cpp
Wizard::Wizard(string name, string lastname, Vector<string> subjects, Haus haus) :
  name{name}, lastname{lastname}, subjects{subjects}, haus{haus}
{
  if (name.empty() || lastname.empty() ){
    throw runtime_error("name or lastname wrong");
  }
}

string Wizard::get_name() const {
  return name;
}

string Wizard::get_lastname() const {
  return lastname;
}

Vector<string> Wizard::get_subjects() const {
  return subjects;
}

Haus Wizard::get_haus() const {
  return haus;
}

Vector<Wizard> v;
Wizard harry("Harry", "Potter", {"magic", "music"}, Haus::Gryffindor);
Wizard ron("Ron", "Weasley", {"magic", "dancing"}, Haus::Gryffindor);
Wizard hermione("Hermione", "Granger", {"magic", "defence"}, Haus::Gryffindor);
Wizard laura("Laura", "Someone", {"running", "sports"}, Haus::Slytherin);

v.push_back(harry);
v.push_back(ron);
v.push_back(hermione);
v.push_back(laura);


Vector<Wizard> cpy;

// v is the original vector of all wizards

copy_if(v.begin(), v.end(), back_inserter(cpy), [](const Wizard& w) {
  return(any_of(w.get_subjects().begin(), w.get_subjects().end(), [](const string& s) {
    return s.find('p') != string::npos;
   }));
 });
```

I end up with exit code 11

Comment: most importantly : Weasley !

Comment: If I remember rightly, that's a segfault. Did you debug your program with your debugger?

Comment: Does `w.get_subjects()` return by reference or by value? Present a [mcve].

Comment: Without seeing the definition of `Wizard`, this cannot be answered exactly. However, I am a bit of a wizard myself, and my divination skills are telling me `get_subjects` returns a container by value. Is that true?

Comment: @Angew lol, jinx...

Comment: to explain: In case get_subjects returns by value, `any_of` will "overflow", because by `++`'ing `w.get_subjects().begin()`, you will never end up with `w.get_subjects().end()`, because this  is referring to another container

Comment: @kawillzocken Actually it's UB to compare the two iterators in the first place. But there's a reason both myself and Angew did _not_ explain: (a) we don't wish to reward posting incomplete questions, and (b) we don't _know_ that's the problem yet, and (c) answers don't go in the comments section.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude the `'p'` in `"sports"` is equal to `'p'`

Comment: @Angew I have inserted it above

Comment: @kawillzocken ahaha :)))) done

Comment: It's still not a [mcve] though. We do have enough information to answer this (indeed, we had enough to guess at it before as you've seen) but you really should make a [mcve] for your questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For starters declare the function `get_subjects` like

```
const Vector<string> & Wizzard::get_subjects() const {
  return subjects;
}
```

Otherwise in this call of the algorithm

```
any_of(w.get_subjects().begin(), w.get_subjects().end(),...);
```

`begin` and `end` return iterators of different ranges (vectors).

Answer (score 8):

You're using *values* everywhere, including in the return type of `get_subjects()`.

Because of that, the two iterators below:

```
w.get_subjects().begin(), w.get_subjects().end()
```

refer to completely separate, unrelated *copies* of the vector.

Comparing iterators to two unrelated vectors has undefined behaviour and this can never work.

Instead, your accessors should return by (const) reference.